# Java compiles but not Executes

Tags: java, compiling, paths

I tried many ways to execute but it is showing the same error

> Error: Could not find or load main class corePKI_Pkg.AppKeyUtil

[image: PF the Screen shot for the compile & execute, Java version, PKG I am using in code and for how directories i am manging and jar file]

Comment: You might find answer here [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

I just added a dot(.) in classpath  along with the jar file and now it is executing, have a look.

[image: Screenshot: Required Output I was expecting]

For more details please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) regarding "*ClassPath*" or "*Could not find or load main class ...*"